# "Invalid value at 'ciphertext' (TYPE_BYTES)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

**SITUATION:**

I am trying to download and decrypt some data from my google cloud bucket.

For encryption and decryption, I use:

https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/quickstart#decrypt_data

Sadly, I get an error : "Invalid value at 'ciphertext' (TYPE_BYTES)".

I know the cyphertext is correct, I believe this may be an issue with the type of data expected by the Google KMS API, i.e.: when retrieving the encrypted data, my code somehow changed it's type before sending the POST request to the Google KMS API.

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it ?

---

**CODE:**

```
gcs.bucket(bucketName)
.file('mysecret.txt.encrypted.txt')
.download({ destination: 'mysecret.txt.encrypted.txt' })
.then(() => {
    fs.readFile('mysecret.txt.encrypted.txt', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("DATA: "+data);
        var formData = {
           ciphertext: data, 
        };
        request.post({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'
            },
            url: 'https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/kms-raimarketplace/locations/global/keyRings/.../cryptoKeys/...:decrypt',
            form: formData
        },
        function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: "+err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("BODY: "+body);
            }
            console.log(err, body);
        });
    });
}).catch(e => {
    console.error('getEnv.js: There was an error: ${JSON.stringify(e, undefined, 2)}');
});
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
BODY: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'ciphertext' (TYPE_BYTES), ",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "ciphertext",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'ciphertext' (TYPE_BYTES), "
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the request library you are using. It appears that the "form" option for request.post formats the body as application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of JSON. Instead, try using the "json" option.

    request.post({json: formData})

Comment: How did you get the encrypted data? The base64 encoding can be tricky: I'm wondering here if your ciphertext is either not base64-encoded for transport or if it's double-encoded.

Comment: @RussAmos `BODY: [object Object]
null { error: 
   { code: 400,
     message: 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "type" at \'ciphertext\': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "data" at \'ciphertext\': Cannot find field.',
     status: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
     details: [ [Object] ] } }`

Comment: If you're Googling this like I did about 4 hours ago...and, like me, you habitually add newlines to your text files (including `mysecret.txt.encrypted.txt`...), you probably ran into the same issue I did, which is that `data` includes a self-induced trailing newline -- which is indeed not valid Base64. Assuming the rest of the contents of `mysecret.txt.encrypted.txt` is already base64 encoded, try passing `ciphertext: data.toString().trim()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are possibly not passing base64-encoded ciphertext; this is the error returned when such decoding fails (although this message can occur in other situations as well).

I created a world-usable key which anyone can use to decrypt, you should be able to use this to test.

Here's the code I used to create the ciphertext. (You will not be able to run this code because I have not opened up encrypt rights on the key. This code is straight out of the [Cloud KMS Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/quickstart#encrypt_data) with my key inserted and the base64 encoding inline)

```
curl -s -X POST "https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/cloud-kms-demonstration/locations/global/keyRings/insecure-example-key-ring/cryptoKeys/insecure-example-key:encrypt" \
-d "{\"plaintext\":\"$(echo hello world | base64)\"}" \
  -H "Authorization:Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

When I run this, I get the following output (I ran it in GCP Cloud Shell logged in as my gmail account, which I'd granted encrypt rights on the key):

```
{
  "name": "projects/cloud-kms-demonstration/locations/global/keyRings/insecure-example-key-ring/cryptoKeys/insecure-example-key/cryptoKeyVersions/1",
  "ciphertext": "CiQAOay+bYR0HXjYHihHZmjPnu0ZEdOm4/HW4S6ZBifwWfFnL1QSNQBA6mRpHiq1MPQ7MerLyJ+gFJdeQooBFU0K0YmGlxRy5Ke/2eV16yR0viHPII6flFpzxnmD"
}
```

So then I ran the following command; you will see that I copied and pasted the ciphertext from the output of the encrypt operation. Anyone who is authenticated will be able to run this command to decrypt the ciphertext with my key, so feel free to run it now:

```
curl -s -X POST "https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/v1/projects/cloud-kms-demonstration/locations/global/keyRings/insecure-example-key-ring/cryptoKeys/insecure-example-key:decrypt" \
  -d "{\"ciphertext\":\"CiQAOay+bYR0HXjYHihHZmjPnu0ZEdOm4/HW4S6ZBifwWfFnL1QSNQBA6mRpHiq1MPQ7MerLyJ+gFJdeQooBFU0K0YmGlxRy5Ke/2eV16yR0viHPII6flFpzxnmD\"}" \
  -H "Authorization:Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

And I got the result:

```
{
  "plaintext": "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQK"
}
```

Which is the base64 encoding of my plaintext:

```
$ echo "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQK" | base64 -d
hello world
```

If I was using a library, it's possible that it would handle the base64 encoding as a part of transport requirements. So hopefully you can use this known-good ciphertext and a key you can decrypt it with to debug your own code. Good luck!

Note: As the names indicate, *do not* use the key I've provided for anything secure (this is why I didn't open encrypt rights on the key).

Comment: That's not how this works, you can't get anyone's credentials from them using a key, any more than I could steal your Google password from you looking at a Google doc. (Also, FWIW, I am the engineering director responsible for Google Cloud KMS; I'm just trying to help.)

Comment: ...if this constitutes a security breach or not. Thank you very much for the help btw, I got the request working as I wanted to ! I was just wondering if a request to another project with $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) in the authorization header would expose the token (I would think so) to the owner of said other project and said user could then use the auth token to gain unwarranted access to resources.

Comment: Depends on what you mean as "me". The URL I posted is not my personal URL: it's the Google Cloud API endpoint. You're talking to Google and the fact that you're making use of a key that I control gives me no access to your identity or credentials. Now, I happen to work at Google, and sure, Google has access to the identity you use when accessing GCP. But I, as an employee, even as a senior employee who runs the service, have no access to that information.

Comment: That said, it's a reasonable concern: if I had inserted a bad hostname that I controlled, you would be sending me a token which would let me use Google APIs as you. Thanks for the concern! (But in this case, *.googleapis.com is safe to use.)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :)